# How to access the file path of uploaded files in fastify

Tags: node.js, fastify, fastify-multipart

When using a form to upload some files I can see in dev tools in the network inspector and specifically in the payload tab under form data, in `view source`.

Note the below includes the file name including the path `twoItems/Screenshot...` its this path `twoItems` I need to access in the API but can't.

Security? Err why do I want this?
It's for a document management app, users cant be creating folders in the browser and then add the files. They need to drag and drop nested directories of files.

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydJ6knkAHgNW7SIF7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="twoItems/Screenshot 2022-03-11 at 08.58.24.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarydJ6knkAHgNW7SIF7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="twoItems/Screenshot 2022-03-11 at 08.58.08.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

so in the API I have a standard fastify API running

```
mport Fastify, { FastifyInstance, RouteShorthandOptions } from "fastify";
import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";

const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const { pipeline } = require("stream");
const pump = util.promisify(pipeline);

const fastify: FastifyInstance = Fastify({});
fastify.register(require("fastify-multipart"));
fastify.register(require("fastify-cors"), {
  methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST"],
});

const dir = "./files";
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

fastify.post("/upload", async (req: any, reply) => {
  console.log(req);
  const parts = await req.files();
  for await (const part of parts) {
    console.log(part); //---------------- LOG BELOW
    await pump(part.file, fs.createWriteStream(`./files/${part.filename}`));
  }
  reply.send();
});

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen(3001);
    const address = fastify.server.address();
    const port = typeof address === "string" ? address : address?.port;
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
start();
```

I can't find how to access the path of each item

when I log out `part` I get...

```
<ref *1> {
  fieldname: 'file',
  filename: 'Screenshot 2022-03-11 at 17.52.11.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  file: FileStream {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: [Object], tail: [Object], length: 4 },
      length: 208151,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Function (anonymous)],
      limit: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    bytesRead: 208151,
    truncated: false,
    _read: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  fields: { file: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Circular *1] ] },
  _buf: null,
  toBuffer: [AsyncFunction: toBuffer]
}
```

this is undefined...

```
console.log(part.path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the busboy's option:

```
fastify.register(require("fastify-multipart"), {
  preservePath: true
});
```

You can find all the options here: https://github.com/fastify/busboy#busboy-methods